# grep does not exclude code comment lines with the "-o" option

Tags: awk, grep

come to your help by using the grep command.
I have problems when I use the -o parameter.
If I don't use this parameter, the search filters me well and excludes the comments of the "//" code, but if I add this parameter it adds these lines by mistake.

My code works fine like this (This grep excludes me the comments "//"):

```
grep -E -n -r 'asegurados,| asegurados |:asegurados' --include *.java  tesoreria/ | grep -v '//'  > tablas.txt
```

the result is:

> CuentaCorrientePolizaDAOImpl.java:4494:       + " select * from asegurados

Now, if I add the parameter "-o", it includes the comment lines "//":

```
grep -E -n -r -o 'asegurados,| asegurados |:asegurados' --include *.java  tesoreria/ | grep -v '//'  > tablas.txt
```

the result is:

> CuentaCorrientePolizaDAOImpl.java:4494:asegurados
> CuentaCorrientePolizaDAOImpl.java:4497:asegurados
> CuentaCorrientePolizaDAOImpl.java:4498:asegurados

lines 4497 and  4498 correspond to comments:

> // Deberá completarse con 0 para los asegurados que estén
> // Deberá completarse con 0 para los asegurados que estén cubiertos con el servicio

Comment: You've shown several outputs but not any input that you'd get that output from. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your input, output, and code as "Code Blocks" and then [edit] your question to do so.